# Trouble calling bash from within python

Tags: android, python, bash, shell

I am trying to use python to help do some automation around an incremental build function in the Android build system.  Generally, from a given directory, I would execute the following command to build whatever is in that directory and subdirectories:

```
mm -j8
```

This is analogous to a "make" command, only it is incremental build and is defined as a function in a bash file called envsetup.sh.  What is does it not important, just know that it's a function defined in a bash script somewhere in the file system.  To execute this, I can also do:

```
bash -c ". /path/to/envsetup.sh; mm -j8"
```

This method of calling it will be important in calling the function from python.  I have followed the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5826523/343381) which shows how to call a function within a bash script from python.  I have used this method in a simple script that, in theory, should just spit out the STDOUT and STDERR from executing the command:

```
import subprocess

command = ['bash', '-c', '. /path/to/envsetup.sh; mm -j8']
(stdout, stderr) = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()

print 'stdout: ' + stdout
print 'stderr: ' + stderr
```

The call to `Popen`, however, never returns.  What am I doing wrong that would allow bash to execute the command properly, but Python hangs when executing the command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl; dr:

Your issue is the use of `shell=True`. Set it to `shell=False` and it'll work.

With this option set, python will just run the first element of the `command` array, i.e. `bash` as a shell script. So currently, python is launching a shell of its own, in order to run your command (`bash`). It'll run bash with no arguments, and bash will then wait for input, blocking your python script.

The `shell=True` setting is for use cases where you are passing a shell script in as a single string. When you're explicitly specifying a shell and its parameters as the process to invoke, as you are doing above, you should set `shell=False`.

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.Popen(['bash', 'whatever'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()
```

Here's what the proces tree looks like when I run the above:

```
  \_ python
      \_ /bin/sh -c bash whatever
          \_ bash
```

The `whatever` is actually passed in, but it's a parameter to the `sh`, not a parameter to the inner `bash`, so the command being run is effectively `['/bin/sh', '-c', 'bash', 'whatever']`, which is quite different from `['/bin/sh', '-c', 'bash whatever']`