# subprocess.Popen: mkvirtualenv not found

Tags: python, virtualenvwrapper

I'm using virtualenvwrapper in my deployment. To setup new environments, I'm running a python script, which contains all needed steps.

The setupscript includes:

```
cmd = 'mkvirtualenv %s --no-site-packages'%('testname')
head = subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
for line in head.stdout.read().splitlines():
    print line
```

The output is:

```
/bin/sh: mkvirtualenv: not found
```

How can I correctly use virtualenvwrapper within my python script?

### EDIT:

The following code works for me:

```
cmd = 'source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh && mkvirtualenv %s --no-site-packages'%('testname')
head = subprocess.Popen(cmd, executable='bash', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
for line in head.stdout.read().splitlines():
    print line
```

Thanks for all answers.

Comment: It's worth noting that your source line will break on most machines other than your own. Let me know if you want this to work on other people's machine and I can write up some bash for you, but if you just want this on your local machine it's fine.

Comment: The whole setup script is written for a special server layout, so for me there is no need for general solution at the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mkvirtualenv` might be a shell function that is added to your environment by sourcing [`virtualenvwrapper.sh` script from your shell's startup file](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#introduction). The default command invoked on `shell=True` (e.g., `/bin/sh -c ...`) might not read it.

You could source the file explicitly:

```
import pipes
from subprocess import check_call

check_call("""source /path/to/virtualenvwrapper.sh &&
    mkvirtualenv --no-site-packages """ + pipes.quote(envname),
    executable='bash', shell=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Edit:

I learned that `mkvirtualenv` is a shell function. In this case the question becomes `how to run shell function in python`. My answer below can be applied to standalone binaries. For your question, please look at the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5826523/1906700 You can indirectly call mkvirtualenv() function from the script that defines it.

## Set PATH variable correctly

The problem seems to be caused by your `$PATH` variable. You need to correctly set this variable so that `mkvirtualenv` executable can be found. For example, if you have `mkvirtualenv` executable in `/home/thore/scripts, you need to set your $PATH in .bashrc or .zshrc (depending on your shell) as follows:

```
 export PATH=$PATH:/home/thore/scripts
```

In that way, `mkvirtualenv` script will be found correctly and run.

### Another Solution

The other solution to the problem would be using the exact path for the script in question. In that case, you can give `/home/thore/scripts/mkvirtualenv` as a parameter to subprocess.

Comment: `mkvirtualenv` is not a script. It's a shell function. http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Ah, then the question becomes how to run a bash function inside a python script. Updating the comment.