# how do you install requirements to arbitrary virtualenv in python scripts?

Tags: python, bash, scripting, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I am trying to install requirements for each project in a list automatically into its own virtualenv. I have gotten to the point of making the virtualenv correctly, but I cannot get it to activate and install requirements into only that virtualenv:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess, sys, time, os

HOMEPATH = os.path.expanduser('~')

CWD = os.getcwd()

d = {'cwd': ''}


if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    projects = sys.argv[1:]


def call_sp(command, **arg_list):
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, **arg_list)
    p.communicate()

def my_makedirs(path):
    if not path.startswith('/home/cchilders'):
        path = os.path.join(HOMEPATH, path)
    try: os.makedirs(path)
    except: pass

for project in projects:
    path        = os.path.join(CWD, project)
    my_makedirs(path)
    git_string = 'git clone git@bitbucket.org:codyc54321/{}.git {}'.format(project, d['cwd'])
    call_sp(git_string)
    d = {'executable': 'bash'}
    call_sp("""source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh && mkvirtualenv --no-site-packages {}""".format(project), **d)
    # call_sp("""source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh && workon {}""".format(project), **d)
    # below, the dot (.) means the same as 'source'. the dot doesn't error, calling source does
    call_sp('. /home/cchilders/.virtualenvs/{}/bin/activate'.format(project))
    d = {'cwd': path}
    call_sp("pip install -r requirements.txt", **d)
```

It works up to

```
call_sp("""source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh && mkvirtualenv --no-site-packages {}""".format(project), **d)
```

but when the script ends, I am not active in the venv and the venv does not have any packages from requirements. Both efforts to source the venv (the one commented out and live) both fail.

The answer that helped me get the mkvirtualenv to work is [subprocess.Popen: mkvirtualenv not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337767/subprocess-popen-mkvirtualenv-not-found).

I also noticed I have a need to do more than just pip install, in one case I need to run 'python setup.py mycommand' which automates setup for each project. How can run commands as if a virtualenv is activated and also install dependencies to arbitrary venvs in a python script?

The only way I've found around this is turning the virtualenv on by hand, then calling my python script by hand. I was surprised, turning it on by bash worked, but calling the python script bombed (maybe because it's a different process than the bash one)

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This is the way I have done this kind of bootstrapping for virtual environments. Let the script take care of it's own env and just run the script. Running this app.py will setup its VE and modules if missing.

./requirements.txt file

```
flask
```

./app.py script

```
#!/bin/bash
""":"
VENV=$(realpath -s $(dirname $0)/ve)
PYTHON=$VENV/bin/python

if [ ! -f "$PYTHON" ]; then
    echo "installing env app"
    python3 -m venv $VENV
    ${VENV}/bin/pip install -r $(dirname $0)/requirements.txt
fi

exec $PYTHON $0 $@
"""

import flask
print("I am Python with flask", flask)
```

No matter what dir we are in, app.py bootstrapps though the bash script header, installing a ve if python does not exist, running pip, and whatever else you need. Then `exec $PYTHON $0 $@` is a slick way to swap out bash process for the python process keeping the same pid.

When python takes over, it skips over the bash part because that script is in triple quotes string. So the first line python executes is `import flask` (well it discards the bash script string 1st). Another cool thing is the pid of the bash process is the same as the pid of the python process. So any daemon utility that babysits this will still see the pid it started.

The last trick in this is that bash needs one extra quote to balance its string `""":"` at the top. Python does not care about that extra quote

I hope you see the pattern. To upgrade modules in requirements.txt, just rm the ve and run the app again. Simple.

Answer (score 1):

This is because each call_sp call creates a new shell,  so after the first call to call_sp ends all the settings created by sourcing of virtualenvwrapper are gone.  You have to combine all your commands into the single call_sp chain.   Otherwise you can just start shell using 'Popen'  and feed commands to it using communicate.

If you go with the later you need to be careful with synchronizing and detecting when installation of requirements ends.   Pip can take a long time downloading and installing packages with complex dependencies.

Comment: my coworker said I can call it with the python in the venv, and the pip file in the venv. I'm testin it now. Thanks for your explanation, combining bash and python is gettin hairy