# Run virtualenvwrapper commands from python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

When I'm trying to create a new Python 3 virtual environment by using `mkvirtualenv` (virtualenvwrapper command) and `os.system` like this

```
import os
os.system('mkvirtualenv foo')
```

nothing happens.

```
os.system("mate-terminal -e 'workon foo'")
```

doesn't work either.

The point is to quickly create a new virtual env and work on it later for each project (it's an automation script). `virtualenvwrapper` is the most convenient option.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943208/activate-a-virtualenv-with-a-python-script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [subprocess.Popen: mkvirtualenv not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337767/subprocess-popen-mkvirtualenv-not-found)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenvwrapper%5D+mkvirtualenv+subprocess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mkvirtualenv` and `workon` commands are shell functions, not executables in your `PATH`[0].
 To make them available in the shell you execute them in, you need to source the `virtualenvwrapper.sh` shell script defining them. You might be better off calling `virtualenv /path/to/foo` directly.

How to activate that virtualenv is another story, though, and will depend on the context you want to use it in. If you activate it in a subprocess, each process using it will have to be run in or under that child.

Hth,
dtk

PS In addition, you might look into the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module (or even the third-party [`sh`](https://amoffat.github.io/sh/)) for calling external programs. Happy coding :)

[0]: See `$ which workon` in a terminal vs `$ which bash`

Comment: Unfortunately, neither subprocess nor sh doesn't help (can't find a perfect solution). However, os.system('python3 -m venv foo') works well, the only con is that it just can't activate it automatically. os.system("mate-terminal -e '. bin/activate'") fails (permission denied). In other words, everything is almost perfect for now, except I need to type 'workon foo' in the popped-out terminal window each time. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: `subprocess` and `sh` don't solve the general problem, however they are nicer interfaces for calling external programs.

Comment: The `permission denied` problem seems to be related to how you execute your command with `-e`/`-x` (and maybe `source`/`.` being shell built-ins instead of executables ;)). And since the terminal you spawned that way will close anyway after it finishes the provided command, you might wanna open a new question for this problem 

Answer (score 0):

The following codes in the bash shell script

```
env_name="<your env name>"
echo "Create virtual environment"
source `which virtualenvwrapper.sh`
mkvirtualenv $env_name -p python<$version>
source $HOME/.virtualenvs/$env_name/bin/activate
workon $env_name
```

then run bash script (for example: `test.sh`) from terminal `source test.sh`