# How to call Bash Script function from Python Script

Tags: python, bash

Suppose I have two functions function_arguments1 and function_agruments2 which are accepting parameters. I want to call the function name:- function_argument1, from python script. How should I call the function_arguments1 from Python passing parameters from python script.

```
#!/bin/bash  
#Script to pass and access arguments  
  
function_arguments1(){  
    echo $1  
    echo $2  
    echo $3  
    echo $4  
    echo $5  
}  
  

function_argument2(){
    echo $1  
    echo $2  
}

#Calling function_arguments2  
function_arguments2 "Please""Help"
```

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/q/5826427/2975396

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a python script execute a function inside a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826427/can-a-python-script-execute-a-function-inside-a-bash-script)

Comment: Actually, no because it is directly calling the function I have to pass the argument from python to bash. Thanks BTW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(['bash', '-c', '. bash_script.sh; function_argument2 Please Help'])
```

To pass input arguments from a list:

```
inputs = ['Hello', 'How', 'What']

for input_ in inputs:
       subprocess.Popen(['bash', '-c', f'. bash_script.sh; function_argument2 {input_}'])
```

Comment: Thank you so much working ... I had spent 1 week to figure out this thing. Thank You so much 

Comment: Hey, i have one doubt lets say i have to repeat this process again and again. so i will the for loop like for i in function_call_list: (function call list is a list of parameters say ['Hello', 'How', 'What']. So when i write the subprocess.Popen(['bash', '-c', '. bash_script.sh; function_argument2 i ']) i value it is not taking. what should i do

Comment: I have updated the answer with the solution